# Create custom Bluetooth 'connect to' shortcut

Tags: windows-7, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

My initial situation is that I work at home on my MacBook but with an external display, a cable-keyboard and a MightyMouse (Bluetooth) and the notebook's lid is closed.

Sometimes the mouse loses connection. Then I have to open the lid, move the trackpad-controlled cursor to the bluetooth icon, connect to my MightMouse again and close the lid again. Very unhandy.

I want to create a keyboard shortcut that instantly triggers the 'Connect' item in the menu drop down from Bluetooth for my device. I have BetterTouchTool which can create a lot of awesome shortcuts, but apparently not for right-hand side menu bar items such as Bluetooth.

Comment: Are you using OSX or are you using Windows 7 via Bootcamp?

Comment: I am using OS X. Yosemite actually.

Comment: This might be missing the point but have you tried just clicking the mouse? I switch my mighty mouse off every night and when I come into work I just switch it on, click once or twice and it autoconnects... Are you not seeing this behaviour?

Comment: I tried that. Like it lost connection and then I tried to turn it off and on again (IT Crowd style). But it just doesn't reconnect itself... It only does when I navigate with my mouse to the Bluetooth icon and click Connect. And there's where the problem starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for reconnecting the Bluetooth-mouse without actually using a mouse. This is on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

1. Make sure under System preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts the Full Keyboard Access is set to All Controls. That means that you can switch between ALL interface control items with the Tab key.
2. In that preference go to Keyboard and activate the option 'Move focus to status menus' and set  shortcut that is convenient for you. I chose ctrl+D.
3. When you press it, it highlights the right-hand side of the menu bar. Navigate with arrow keys to the Bluetooth icon and use the down-arrow to navigate in the Bluetooth menu and the right-arrow to go to the Connect option of the device you want to re-connect.
4. Press Enter and it will re-connect the device.